# Is it possible to have div background with opacity but with gradient some pixel borders?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 0.5 transparency. This acts as a darkening rectangle over a bigger background slider image (an outer div) to make the text more readable over the slider background picture.

```
<div class="darken-rectangle">
   <!-- inner text container divs go here -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.darken-rectangle {
   padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

This works great, however I would like to a few pixel (3px-6px) gradient border for the rectangle which drives the alpha from the outer light to the inner darken.

Unfortunately I can not find how to do this, even does not know is it possible with pure CSS, or do I have to create 4 png images for the 4 "border and arrange the layout?

Comment: How are you adding the border currently? Can we see that?

Comment: There is no CSS border. I used the "border" term in pure English meaning. The whole CSS is what is in the sample. See picture I am going to add. If the efficient solution is adding CSS border (what I also searched in google) please let me know how could it be _gradient_, and how could the corners gradient rendered correctly

Comment: Ok, what are the browsers that the solution should support? IE11+ and other modern browsers is sufficient or you need to support the older ones?

Comment: Luckily I would not like to support older browsers. However the solution should gracefully fall back to "without gradients" rendering what is on the picture.

Comment: What about this exactly gradient? http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,000000+100&0.65+26,0.65+91,0+100

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vykr6qtL/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="darken-rectangle">
    Test Text
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.darken-rectangle {
    /* ... */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.darken-rectangle {
   padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer as to why this will solve the problem